# Poll with Age restriction

Tags: javascript, html

Want to create a poll with age restriction under javascript. Problem is I dont know how to create the code by myself should I add a variable like age under javascript or in html? Thanks for answering.

Comment: first thing to learn. though java and javascript seem the same, they're not related

Comment: The answer to the only "question" in the post is simple: You create the variable to JS, since HTML doesn't implement variables.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp